# How do I start yarn without getting the following error?

Tags: node.js, terminal, yarnpkg, yarn-v2

After installing the dependencies needed, I try to start the development server by typing yarn run start in the terminal, and I get the following output:

```
yarn run v1.22.17

Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
   
 at Object.readSync (node:fs:723:3)
    
at tryReadSync (node:fs:433:20)
   
 at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:479:19)
    
at onUnexpectedError (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.17/libexec/lib/cli.js:92686:106)
   
 at /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.17/libexec/lib/cli.js:92805:9
```

What can I do to get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this by having a directory called `package.json`.

```
/v/f/n/8/T/tmp.CgVFBaEa $ mkdir package.json
/v/f/n/8/T/tmp.CgVFBaEa $ yarn
yarn install v1.22.11
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Object.readSync (node:fs:720:3)
    at tryReadSync (node:fs:430:20)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:476:19)
    at onUnexpectedError (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.11/libexec/lib/cli.js:92566:106)
    at /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.11/libexec/lib/cli.js:92685:9
```

Make sure you don't have a directory called `package.json` (or `yarn.lock`, I'd guess).

Comment: Thank you for the help! When I remove it, I get the following error `error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/Users/ghofranezirouh"
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.`. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You really shouldn't be starting a project in your user folder...